# use jquery datetime picker inside an asp.net content page and repeater control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sql, asp.net

I need to add java script tag in content page of asp.net application. The script works fine with html tags but in content it is not working here is the code.
This is my code to display datetime picker :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery.ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(function dtTimePicker()
        {
            $("txtDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear:true

            });
        });
    </script>
    <hr />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDate" Text="Search" OnClick="btnDate_Click"></asp:Button>
    <hr />
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1>MANHOUR</h1>
        <hr />
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <!-- Default panel contents -->
            <div class="panel-heading">DAILYDATAWH</div>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptrDAILYDATAWH" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>

                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>STATUSIN</th>
                                <th>NIP</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <th><%# Eval("STATUSIN") %></th>
                        <th><%# Eval("NIP") %></th>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="defaultItem" runat="server" 
                        Visible='<%# rptrDAILYDATAWH.Items.Count == 0 %>' Text="No items found" />
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>    
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

and this is my code on backend :

```
 protected void btnDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl body = (HtmlGenericControl)Page.Master.FindControl("pagebody");
            body.Attributes.Add("onload", "dtTimePicker();");
            String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MANHOURConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[DAILYDATAWH] WHERE STATUSIN=@STATUSIN", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUSIN", txtDate.Text);
            DataTable dtDaily = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dtDaily);

            rptrDAILYDATAWH.DataSource = dtDaily;
            rptrDAILYDATAWH.DataBind();
        }
```

I want to filter datetime in `STATUSIN` and get the records from database with selected date. How to place jquery datetime picker inside content page with repeater control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CDN for the datepicker is wrong try replacing this

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery.ui.min.js
```

with this (notice the diff between `jquery.ui` and `jquery-ui`).

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js
```

And try replace the asp:net component for the datepicker with html component and select the id by using $('#...')

```
   <pre>
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
          <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link  rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            $(function dtTimePicker() {
                $("#txtDate").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true
    
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
        <input type="text" id="txtDate"/>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDate" Text="Search" OnClick="btnDate_Click"></asp:Button>
        <hr />
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1>MANHOUR</h1>
            <hr />
        </div>
    </pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

By "doesn't work" I presume you mean the datepicker doesn't render correctly ?

Firstly, `$("txtDate").datepicker({` - you haven't included an ID selector, so it would be `$("#txtDate").datepicker({`

However inside a repeater, `$("txtDate").datepicker({` is not going to work for your `<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate">` because each instance of the textbox inside your repeater is not going to have 'txtDate' as its ID; it will have a generated ID that the naming container (the repeater) will generate. If you inspect the HTML using browser debug tools you can confirm this.

If all you need to do is render the textbox as a jQuery datepicker, use a Class selector instead, i.e.

`<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate" CssClass="datepick">`

and change your jQuery to

`$(".datepick").datepicker({`

Comment: Thanks for helping me. i've been try to change with `$("#txtDate").datepicker` and try with CssClass but still not work too. The datetime picker still not appear

Comment: So when you added a CssClass to your textbox, did you also update the jQuery selector to `$(".datepick")` ? (or whatever your class name is) If this doesn't work, are you getting any errors in the browser debug console ?

Comment: yes, i did update the jQuery selector, but still doesn't work. i'm not getting any errors in the browser debug console

Comment: when i click a button it's actually work because it's show the label item : "No items found". But, why the datetime picker is still not appear?

Answer (score 0):

Your code have a few problems, for example you are calling the `dtTimePicker` in `onload` or you are a wrong selector `txtDate` to select the input. Also the format of the year is incorrect, however not very important.

No matter you want to show the date picker inside the repeater or outside of repeater, assign a class like `datepicker` to the `CssClass` attribute of the control. Then in document ready, call select `.datepicker` using the class selector and apply date picker on it.

**Example**

I assume you are looking for a minimal working example, so I will share a minimal working example as your start point.  Here is a very minimal example that you can test without any code behind. Just copy the following code and paste in a `Form1.aspx` file and browse the `Form1.aspx` to see the following output:

[image: DatePicker]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="System.Web.UI.Page" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Form1</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Date:" Font-Bold="true" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker" />
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Birth date</th>
                        </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="BirthDateTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker"
                                Text='<%# Eval("BirthDate", "{0:dd-MMMM-yyyy}") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
        var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("BirthDate", typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Rows.Add("Mario Speedwagon", new DateTime(1980, 11, 5));
        dt.Rows.Add("Petey Cruiser", new DateTime(1975, 7, 9));
        Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but is it work if it's as content page? because, i have master page and want to place the datetime picker in content page

Comment: Yes, it will work. I just tried to make the example as minimal as possible to be easily verifiable and be a good start point for you to achieve what you need. You can put all the script and style tags of the head into the master page. The point is in using a css class and using document ready.

Comment: but, it's doesn't show how to connect to Master Page like this `MasterPageFile="~/AdminMaster.Master"`

Comment: I have tried to keep the example as minimal as possible, by not using a master page, even by not using a code behind file, by not using db. It looks like you know how to use master page or how to use code behind file. If you have any specific problem in applying the solution let me know what complexity or problem have you have faced with and I'll help you if I can.

Comment: i've been try it, but it's not the output that i meant. I want to show the records have same date with selected date

Comment: @DeaAnanda It's pretty hard to continue answering the question. Could you please edit the question and make the question clearer: **(1)** Are you trying to show datepicker in repeater or for the text box above? The question is talking about repeater but in the code I see you are trying to show it for the textbox above the repeater. Also here in the comments it looks like you are trying to show it for textbox above. **(2)** When you say it doesn't work, it's not clear what is not working? Is the problem with your search (query) or do you mean the datepicker doesn't show?

Comment: **(3)** You are searching on `STATUSIN`, while it's not clear what is the type of the column and what are the data format of the vales in the column. **(4)** Please try to keep the question about a specific topic and a specific problem and don't mix every things together. **(5)** Please take a look at [ASK] and [MCVE], you are pretty new to the site and it worth it to read those topics. It will help you to receive more effective help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208383/discussion-between-dea-ananda-and-reza-aghaei).

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function dtTimePicker()
        {
            $("#<%=txtDate.ClientID%>").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear:true

            });
        });
```

This is Incorrect  $("txtDate") as there is  no html tag like txtDate.

Use

```
 $("#txtDate")
```

or

```
$(".txtDate")
```

or

```
$("#<%=txtDate.ClientID%>")
```

try

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

to have txtDate as static id in html also.

```
$('#<%=txtDate.ClientID%>')
```

will find an element with the id attribute as supplied by the ClientID property in ASP.Net.

```
$("[id$=lblName]")
```

will find an element with an id attribute that ends with lblName, for example foo-lblName.